# How to do background uploading using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, background, alamofire

I'm new to Alamofire and I'm trying to upload files even after the app goes to the background.
According to the discussion of this issue on github
[Background downloads](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/194)
Alamofire 1.2 can properly handle background transfer service now.
But I cannot find any tutorials or samples on the internet.
Can someone please show me a path?

Thanks!!